# SugarCRM Request Timeout

Tags: php, linux, apache, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM to fetch records (more than 1000+ records) in Cases.
I already set up config_override.php:

```
$sugar_config['max_record_fetch_size']= 1200;
```

**php.ini:**

`max_execution_time = 3600;`

I still get the timeout error. What else do i need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SugarCRM 7.6, theres a new configuration to override **api.timeout**

```
$sugar_config['api']['timeout'] = 180;  //default 3 minutes
```

so i need to override the time to a higher value for me to avoid the Request timeout error :-)

Answer (score 3):

set max execution time to 0 so that it will not through timeout error...but you need to optimize your code or query to get records.

```
max_execution_time(0);
```

Comment: Im at the search feltering Date Created. Then i tick the box to select all then it will prompt =>
You have selected all 20 records in this view. **Select all** records in the result set.
then i Select All. then after 3 min it goes with a timeout error

Comment: this kind of setting is not advisable, if your application takes too long to load, then there must be a problem on the other parts, this will exhaust the server